# how to convert PNG32 to PNG8 via Imagick in PHP

Tags: php, png, imagick

I want to convert PNG32 to PNG8 via the php Object Imagick.
but I used setImageDepth and setImageFormat setting param to 8bit, it didn't take effect.
the code like this:

```
$im = new Imagick($image);
$im->cropImage($cutWidth,$cutHeight,$x,$y);
$im->thumbnailImage($maxWidth, $maxHeight); 
$im->setImageDepth(8);
$im->setImageFormat('PNG8');
$im->writeImage($filename);
```

inputfile is PNG32, but output above remains PNG8, have other solution?

Answer (score 14):

This seems to be a known problem, so I did some research. Basically, the setImageDepth just isn't enough. You need to quanitize the image. This is a test script that worked for me...

```
$im = new imagick('stupid.png'); //an image of mine
$im->setImageFormat('PNG8');
$colors = min(255, $im->getImageColors());
$im->quantizeImage($colors, Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false );
$im->setImageDepth(8 /* bits */);
$im->writeImage('stupid8.png');
```

Came out nice.

Comment: Lifesaver indeed. I was just about to write my own question regarding conversion of 1-bit B/W image to shrunken grayscale image after struggling a day with getting it to work. Code that worked well on another (older) server. Thanks Greg! guantizeImage() needed to be done after loading the image (obviously).

Comment: need to transparent background or white background how to do it ?

Comment: (in 2022) It gives me a darker colors on output for image with just 2 colors. (for example for #562E25). With no difference in file size in my case.

Comment: Colors can be fixed with SRGB color space -  `Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB`

Comment: Seems to still be the best way to perform a PNG compression in 2024 ! However I replaced `Imagick::COLORSPACE_RBG` with `$im->getColorspace()` .

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question that has already been answered but there is one other shorter way to do this that I discovered. You can force the write format by prefixing the filename with the format (e.g. `png8:outputfile.png`). The question example could be accomplished like this:

```
$im = new Imagick($image);
$im->cropImage($cutWidth,$cutHeight,$x,$y);
$im->thumbnailImage($maxWidth, $maxHeight); 
$im->writeImage("png8:$filename");
```